# PK Index Fragmentation on tables with nvarchar primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Due to some recent database problems we've been having recently, I've been looking at the state of our indexes and trying to reduce the fragmentation.

The app has several tables of names such as BoysNames and GirlsNames which we use to set attributes on User objects we created. The obvious attribute here would be Gender. These tables can have anywhere from a few hundred to 10,000 rows.

These tables are structured like this:

```
Name - nvarchar(50) - PK & Clustered Index
DateCreated - datetime
```

When I tell Sql Server to reorganize or rebuild the indexes on all my tables, most table fragmentaiton goes down to 0%, but some of these Name tables are at 50% fragemented straight away.

I only access these tables in 2 places:

1. The first is when I select every name from the table and store it in
   memory to use against new users coming into the system so I can do something like this: if
   (boysNames.Contains(user.Name)) {user.Gender = "M"}; This happens quite
   often.
2. The second is when I'm adding new names to the list, I check for the
   existance of a name, if it doesn't exist, I add it. This happens
   rarely.

So what I need to know is:

Is this high level of fragmentation going to be causing me problems? How can I reduce the the index fragmentation to 0% when it's being set to 50% straight after a reorganize/rebuild?

Should I have used an int as the primary key and put an index on Name, or was nvarchar the right choice for primary key?

Comment: You can keep your PK on names but create a clustered index on an auto-increment integer

Comment: I thought because these tables are going to be searched A-Z, it's best to have the Clustered Index on the Name as it will speed things up. Or is that now how it works?

Comment: It would fragment your table since the names aren't alphabetically inserted. The PK will create a unique index on the names anyway

Comment: BTW it's not that bad if your table doesn't grow that much, but it's always better to have a good design at the beginning ofc

Comment: How large are the indexes in pages?  If they are < 1000 pages you should expect them to always be fragmented (and you shouldn't worry about it).  The same holds true for extremely large tables.

Answer (score 0):

If the index pages are resident in memory, which is likely with that few rows, fragmentation does not matter. You can benchmark that with a `count(*)` query. Starting with the 2nd execution, you should see in-memory speeds. If you now compare the results for a 100% and a 0% fragmented table, you should see no difference.

I don't think you have a problem. If you insist, you can set a fill factor lower than 100 so that there is room for new rows when you insert rows at random places. Start with 90 and lower it in increments of 5 until you are happy with the rate fragmentation develops.

Clustering on an `IDENTITY` field would remove the fragmentation for the clustered index, but you'd probably need an index on `Name` which again fragments. If you do not need any index at all, make this a heap table and be done with it. I recommend very much against this, though.